# Построение похожих запросов Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Приложение таск-менеджер. Добавил в него пользователей, и теперь получается, чтобы получить, допустим, задачи пользователя, нужно в запросе указывать where('owner_id', $ownerId). Но для пользователя также идут категории, теги, короче куча всего. Какие есть варианты избавиться от дублирования кода, чтобы в запросе каждый раз не указывать where owner_id...?

Вот как я делаю сейчас:

```
return Task::whereNull('parent_id')
        ->with('tags')
        ->where('owner_id', $ownerId)
        ->paginate(5);
```

Сейчас мне нужно получить также категории для пользователя и снова писать where ownerId... Но сразу понятно что такой подход неправильный. Прошу подкинуть идей как реализовать красиво

**P.S.** не все запросы должны содержать запрос на выборку по пользователям

Comment: Для вынесения больших блоков условий, например если данные 3 строки (до paginate) будут использоваться много где, Можно воспользоваться паттерном Repository и там хранить данную логику, которая выдаётся контроллеру. Так же для группировки where с другими where и прочими методами используете laravel scopes. Например выделим owner и parent условия в метод: scopeUserHeadTask(Builder $builder, int $ownerId) ...  Получится так: Task::userHeadTask($ownerId)...

Comment: Можете подсказать какую-нибудь статью про scopes? Как будто это то что мне надо, но идея как реализовать не лезет

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#local-scopes